# Nested Subquery vs Derived table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery, derived-table

I'm learning SQL Server and have a question between nested Subquery vs Derived table using from clause.
Example for nested Subquery where it is using the from clause.
Example was taken from the link : https://www.tutorialgateway.org/sql-subquery/

```
USE [SQL Tutorial]
GO

SELECT subquery.FirstName + ' ' + subquery.LastName AS [Full Name]
    ,subquery.[Occupation]
    ,subquery.[YearlyIncome]
    ,subquery.[Sales]
FROM (
    SELECT [Id]
        ,[FirstName]
        ,[LastName]
        ,[Education]
        ,[Occupation]
        ,[YearlyIncome]
        ,[Sales]
    FROM [Employee Table]
    WHERE [Sales] > 500
    ) AS [subquery]
```

Example for Derived table where it is using the from clause.
Example was taken from the link : https://www.tutorialgateway.org/sql-derived-table/

```
USE [SQLTEST]
GO

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT [EmpID]
        ,[FirstName]
        ,[LastName]
        ,[Education]
        ,[YearlyIncome]
        ,[Sales]
        ,[DeptID]
    FROM [EmployeeDetails]
    ) AS [Derived Employee Details]
WHERE [Sales] > 500
```

what makes the nested subquery different form the derived table.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: They are identical? What is different between your 2 queries? A nested sub-query **IS** a derived table.

Comment: As per your tutorial "The SQL Derived Table is nothing but a Subquery used in the From Clause."

Comment: From the article [SQL syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_syntax#Derived_table) on Wikipedia: "A _derived table_ is the use of referencing an SQL subquery in a FROM clause. Essentially, the derived table is a subquery that can be selected from or joined to. The derived table functionality allows the user to reference the subquery as a table. The inline view is also referred to as an _inline view_ or a _subselect_. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A derived table is specifically a subquery that is used in the `from` clause, that returns a result set with an arbitrary number of columns and rows.

A subquery is more generic and refers to any query-within-a-query.  One type of subquery, for instance, is a *scalar subquery*.  Such a subquery returns at most one row and one column.  It can be used in `select` and `where` (and some other places) where a scalar value can be used.  A scalar subquery can also be used in the `from` clause.